# Consuming web service in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, web-services

I have a normal .asmx web service which loads fine in the browser. When I load the web page with the Silverlight app in it, the data doesn't load and I get a javascript error which states;

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 1 Sep 2010 16:43:32
>   UTC
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight Application An exception
>   occurred during the operation, making
>   the result invalid.  Check
>   InnerException for exception details. 
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at
>   Operations.Dashboard.DashboardMetrics.GetP200MA_CountCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>   at
>   Operations.Dashboard.MainPage.client_GetP200MA_CountCompleted(Object
>   sender,
>   GetP200MA_CountCompletedEventArgs e)
>   at
>   .Operations.Dashboard.DashboardMetrics.MetricsSoapClient.OnGetP200MA_CountCompleted(Object
>   state) Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://ukhqdevmp-3790:8080/ChartTestPage.aspx
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight Application An exception
>   occurred during the operation, making
>   the result invalid.  Check
>   InnerException for exception details. 
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at
>   Operations.Dashboard.DashboardMetrics.GetP200C_CountCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>   at
>   Operations.Dashboard.MainPage.client_GetP200C_CountCompleted(Object
>   sender,
>   GetP200C_CountCompletedEventArgs e)
>   at
>   Operations.Dashboard.DashboardMetrics.MetricsSoapClient.OnGetP200C_CountCompleted(Object
>   state) Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://ukhqdevmp-3790:8080/ChartTestPage.aspx

It all runs fine within VS but when accessing it from another PC via IIS, it doesn't work.

```
MetricsSoapClient client = new MetricsSoapClient();
client.GetP200C_CountCompleted += new EventHandler<DashboardMetrics.GetP200C_CountCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetP200C_CountCompleted);
client.GetP200C_CountAsync(yearStart, yearEnd);
client.GetP200MA_CountCompleted += new EventHandler<DashboardMetrics.GetP200MA_CountCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetP200MA_CountCompleted);
client.GetP200MA_CountAsync(yearStart, yearEnd);

public void client_GetP200C_CountCompleted(object sender, DashboardMetrics.GetP200C_CountCompletedEventArgs e)
{ ...
```

**UPDATE**: Using Fiddler, I can see that it's a security issue, I'm guessing a double-hop one.

Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\UKHQDEVMP-3790$'.

Comment: can you post the code you use to initialize the web service call?

Comment: Sounds like you need to post the contents of the InnerException as well if you want anything useful.

Comment: @Kelsey - I created a new Silverlight 4 project (and associated web app to host it). In the web app I created a web service to publish data from a database using Linq.

I then consume this in my MainPage.xaml.cs using the code below.

Comment: MetricsSoapClient client = new MetricsSoapClient();
client.GetP200C_CountCompleted += new EventHandler<DashboardMetrics.GetP200C_CountCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetP200C_CountCompleted);
client.GetP200C_CountAsync(yearStart, yearEnd);
client.GetP200MA_CountCompleted += new EventHandler<DashboardMetrics.GetP200MA_CountCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetP200MA_CountCompleted);
client.GetP200MA_CountAsync(yearStart, yearEnd);
public void client_GetP200C_CountCompleted(object sender, DashboardMetrics.GetP200C_CountCompletedEventArgs e)
{ ... }

Comment: you should edit your original question when posting more information. I have moved your code into your question. Notice the difference from your code and the code I posted below. Make sure your Uri is correct. Try instantiating your web service like I have and include all the details. I think your webservice is pointing to a local or relative address so moving it causes things to break.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should verify that when you move it to another PC that your webservice address is correct and you are not trying to connect to `localhost` or something relative to your Visual Studio enviroment.

I remember having this issue but very vaguely and I can't remember what my solution was so I went back and looked at some code for a previous project and how the web service was setup.  This is a long shot but maybe my code will help point you in the right direction if the web service setup is incorrect. Check the following line I had and see if it helps with anything (this was done with Silverlight 3):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source,
    "../Services/YourWebService.asmx");

// notice this line is commented out and a * is used for biniding instead
//System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(); // "*"

YourWebService.YourWebServiceSoapClient = 
    new YourWebService.YourWebServiceSoapClient("*",
            new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(uri));
```

Comment: When I add the service reference to the Silverligfht project, it adds all the methods in as per my code comment above. I then use these to add my rendering logic.